# Javascript date format/parse toString() 'Dec 1, 2012'

Tags: javascript, string, date, datetime, format

I need a solution to convert, parse or format Date() toString like 'Dec 1, 2012'. I found this example to String: 'mmm d, yyyy', but it does not work.

Comment: @RavinderSingh When you return, do *not* keep posting comments asking people if your post helped them or to vote/accept your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear as to whether you want to convert a string into a date, or vice versa.

To convert a `Date` object into the format you're looking for:

```
function dateToString(d) {
  var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'][d.getMonth()];
  return month + ' ' + d.getDate() + ', ' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

To convert a string in the format specified to a `Date`:

```
function stringToDate(s) {
  var match = s.match(/^(\w{3}) (\d{1,2}), (\d{4})$/);

  if (match) {
    var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'].indexOf(match[1]);
    return new Date(match[3], month, match[2]);
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Note that `stringToDate` requires [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). This is not supported in all browsers, but can be shim'd.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to parse date manually.

Use this function :

```
// parse a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
function parseDate(input) {
   var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
   // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
   return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dateFormat(Date(), "mmm d, yyyy");
```

does not work?

refer to here:

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

well, sorry - just seen, You have to include:

http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js

to get it work like described in the 1st link...